# How can I affect individual entries in a django for loop?

Tags: jquery, django, tags, truncate

I have created a for loop in Django which displays articles uploaded by users. In the case of long articles I will truncate the text to a max length of 150 chars, but want to give readers the option of expanding the text using a jquery function, by clicking 'read more'.
This is my template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.content|length > 150 %}
        <p class="half-content">{{ post.content|truncatechars:150 }}<a href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read more</a></p>
        <p class="full-content" style="display: none;">{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is my jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show-hide-btn").click(function(){
        $(".half-content").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show-hide-btn").click(function(){
        $(".full-content").show();
    });
});
```

It works how I would like it to, except that the 'read more' link is expanding all the articles on the page, not just the one with the appropriate primary key. I know I need to include {{ post.id }} in my code somewhere, but so far everything I have tried has been ineffective.

Comment: you may use javascript for that

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question

Comment: Read up on selectors. You should limit your action to the sister element of the parent with the "full-content". Or you can make it easy on yourself and just give each post an id and reference that. You can use [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for that - for example or just `{{post.id}}`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My posts all have an id already. Can you please tell me where I should include {{ post.id }} in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.content|length > 150 %}
        <p class="half-content" id="half-{{post.id}}">{{ post.content|truncatechars:150 }}<a data-id="{{post.id}}" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read more</a></p>
        <p class="full-content" id="full-{{post.id}}" style="display: none;">{{ post.content }}</p></div>
    {% else %}
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show-hide-btn").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $("#half-"+id).hide();
            $("#full-"+id).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for your help!