# Read More js in django for loop

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I try to apply this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833286/how-can-i-affect-individual-entries-in-a-django-for-loop) to integrate read more/read less JS into a django template. I want to limit my post app. 200 characters and providing the user the option to Read More.

This script seems to work fine... not so much in my case.
It displays the Read More option but once clicked no event it triggered. That is, it doesn't open the entire text. It displays a colored test 'Read More' but noting else happens.

Here's the answer provided in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833286/how-can-i-affect-individual-entries-in-a-django-for-loop):

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.content|length > 150 %}
        <p class="half-content" id="half-{{post.id}}">{{ post.content|truncatechars:150 }}<a data-id="{{post.id}}" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read more</a></p>
        <p class="full-content" id="full-{{post.id}}" style="display: none;">{{ post.content }}</p></div>
    {% else %}
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show-hide-btn").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $("#half-"+id).hide();
```

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show other i.e : `full-content` when you click on `readmore` so you can use `$("#full-" + id).toggle();` .Also , i have added `read less` text to hide the text which is display .You can add that part here :

```
 <p class="full-content" id="full-{{post.id}}" style="display: none;">{{ post.content }}<a data-id="{{post.id}}" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read less</a></p>
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show-hide-btn").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#half-" + id).toggle();//hide/show..
    $("#full-" + id).toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="half-content" id="half-1">Yes ,you..<a data-id="1" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read more</a></p>
<p class="full-content" id="full-1" style="display: none;">Yes,you..are aweome<a data-id="1" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read less</a></p>
<p class="half-content" id="half-3">Yes..you..<a data-id="3" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read more</a></p>
<p class="full-content" id="full-3" style="display: none;">Yes ..you..can do it..<a data-id="3" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">read less</a></p>
```

Comment: glad i was able to help :)